# How to configure "If the task is already running, then the following rule applies" in Windows Task Scheduler using PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, taskscheduler

[image: Task Scheduler settings page]

I am trying to achieve the following settings (select "If the task is already running, then the following rule applies") through PowerShell script but unable to get appropriate settings to configure that.

**I am using the following code to configure that**

```
$Trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At 07:00am -Daily

$Settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -ExecutionTimeLimit (New-TimeSpan -Hour 1) -Compatibility Win7 -StartWhenAvailable -Priority 7

$User = "SYSTEM"

$Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "some script" -Argument "some argument" -WorkingDirectory "working dir"

Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Test Task" -Trigger $Trigger -User $User -Action $Action -Settings $Settings -RunLevel Highest –Force
```

**To do the advanced configuration for the triggers**

```
$Task = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Example Task"

$Task.Triggers[0].ExecutionTimeLimit = "PT10M"

$Task | Set-ScheduledTask -User $User
```

Comment: Have you tried "getting" a scheduled task which is set this way and looking at the trigger properties?

Comment: Hi @MikeShepard yes I have tried to set up a scheduled task in GUI and check the settings config like $Task = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Example Task"

$Task.Settings but couldn't find any relevant settings to tweak, I believe it will be settings and not trigger

Comment: For CyberArk CPM Logs handling, you can refer to https://docs.cyberark.com/Product-Doc/OnlineHelp/PAS/Latest/en/Content/PASIMP/CPMLogging.htm

Answer (score 2):

The setting is configured via [`New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtasksettingsset) and the parameter you're looking for is `-MultipleInstances`:

> **`-MultipleInstances`**
>
> Specifies the policy that defines how Task Scheduler handles multiple instances of the task. The acceptable values for this parameter are:
>
> IgnoreNew. The new task instance is ignored. Parallel. The new task instance starts immediately. Queue. The new task instance starts as soon as the current instance completes.
>
> Type: `MultipleInstancesEnum`
>   Accepted values:  `Parallel`, `Queue`, `IgnoreNew`
>   Position: Named
>   Default value:    ***None***

However, the documentation lists only 3 values, and the respective enum (at least at the time of this writing also only has the listed 3 values:

- `Parallel` → *Run a new instance in parallel*
- `Queue` → *Queue a new instance*
- `IgnoreNew` → *Do not start a new instance*

If you create a task manually via the GUI and select the setting *"Stop the existing instance"* the value `.Settings.MultipleInstances` is empty, but if you create a Settings object via `New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet` omitting the parameter `-MultipleInstances` it defaults to `IgnoreNew`. Attempts to change that to an empty value result in validation errors.

This is obviously a bug (missing value in the referenced enum).

Comment: I also found this snippet from https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/category/148044/filters/new?page=4

Only Parallel, Queue, and IgnoreNew are supported right now. One would expect that the option available from the Task Scheduler GUI would be available in the powershell interface.

Steps to reproduce

$a = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -MultipleInstances StopExisting

Expected behavior

The task's multiple instances policy is set to kill existing tasks before starting another instance.

Comment: Hi Ansgar  if  I am omitting the parameter value its entirely the scripts fails to run and throws

ew-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet : Missing an argument for parameter 'MultipleInstances'. Specify a parameter of type 
'Microsoft.PowerShell.Cmdletization.GeneratedTypes.ScheduledTask.MultipleInstancesEnum' and try again.

Comment: Hmm... when I manually create a task and select the setting *"stop the existing instance"* I get an empty value for that setting. However, creating a settings object without specifying the parameter `-MultipleInstances` defaults to the setting `IgnoreNew`, and the value of that property cannot be changed to empty, only to a valid value from the enum. This obviously is a bug.

Comment: Hi Ansgar can you guide me to any correct channel or forum where can I raise this issue

Comment: I believe your answer helps explain the root cause of an issue I was having with running scheduled tasks as a service account: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63637743/184546

Answer (score 1):

The enum now contains '**StopExisting**'.

This is my solution in C#.

```
static void RegisterMyTask(string taskPath, string remoteServer)
{
    try
    {
        using TaskService ts = new(remoteServer);
        TaskDefinition taskDef = ts.NewTask();
        taskDef.Settings.MultipleInstances = TaskInstancesPolicy.StopExisting;

        ...
```

However PowerShell probably has the new enum as well. As I would guess:

```
-MultipleInstances StopExisting
```

I had a task scheduled on multiple remote servers.

On day 1 it started running.

Day 2 it failed to start a new instance, but didn't kill the existing instance

Day 3 it failed to start a new instance, but didn't kill the existing instance. Then 30 seconds later, the existing instance was killed by the day 1 timeout setting, but the new instance had already failed for the day.

This fixed my problem.